# How jar plugin using dependency from WEB-INF/lib/*.jar

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies

I build web application using a.jar as a dependency

I build plugin.jar as a plugin for web application and also using a.jar as a dependency

a.jar has b.jar as a dependency.

I build web application as war file and i have:
WEB-INF\lib\a.jar
WEB-INF\lib\b.jar

I build plugin.jar that contain a.jar.

I deploy web application to glassfish and copy plugin.jar to application server\lib.

When i run web application, it through the error on plugin.jar that it can't find class name that in b.jar.

Is a.jar from plugin.jar able to use b.jar from WEB-INF\lib?

Comment: What is `plugin.jar` ? Something special for glassfish ?

Comment: plugin.jar is a library for web application. Just like an add-on for an application.

Comment: So why copying that to server/lib instead of packaging it into the war file?

Comment: Because i want to add or move the plugin depend on user need.